# Is it possible to cross-compile .deb files using debhelper? How?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, deb, architecture, cross-compilation

I have a package (Dymo CUPS drivers in this instance) that I need to compile to a .deb file to include in a private network's repositories. The source itself is sufficiently architecture independent that it'll compile on 32-bit and 64-bit. I am using `debhelper` to build the packages, and have successfully built the package for the native architecture.

Most of the machines run Precise 64-bit, but some run Precise 32-bit. The current build machine is 64-bit. What I want to be able to do is "cross-compile" the package and generate the 32-bit packages from the 64-bit packages.

What I've tried:

- Adding "-a" or "--architecture" flags to `fakeroot debian/rules binary` - fails because it doesn't understand the argument (I must have copied it from a dpkg or other command)
- Add `override_dh_auto_configure` in `debian/rules` that supplies `-m32` for CFLAGS etc - builds as 32-bit, but packages and defines dependencies as a 64-bit package
- Installing `dpkg-cross` and running `fakeroot debian/rules binary-cross` (based on an idea from [these cross-compile instructions](http://psas.pdx.edu/DebianCrossCompilerHowto/)) - fails because binary-cross doesn't exist as a standard `dh` command

Things I can't try:

- Launchpad/PPA/any other external build service - everything needs to be part of our infrastructure

Is there any way to make `debhelper` build 32-bit .deb files on a 64-bit machine? And if so, how?

Comment: As we're working on Ubuntu 12.04, we've decided to go with a 32-bit LXC container for the build. No other methods appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

`debuild -ai386` should set everything up correctly, but it depends on having the proper multiarch build-dependencies installed; it's easier with a recent version of `sbuild` (more recent than is in precise, I'm afraid), and it does depend on all the libraries you use having been converted to multiarch.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CrossBuilding for details.